# Align JTextArea in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I'm currently building GUI with Java Swing.

My current code produces this. [image: Output]

The JTextArea of Product List makes the GUI looks awkward, how can I make the JTextArea looks like this, where it seems to have an extra row:
[image: Desired Output]

The GroupLayout code I'm using is:

```
 gr.setVerticalGroup(gr.createSequentialGroup()
    .addGroup(gr.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE).addComponent(productName).addComponent(productText).addComponent(productList))
    .addGroup(gr.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE).addComponent(amount).addComponent(amountText).addComponent(prodScroll))
    .addGroup(gr.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE).addComponent(description).addComponent(desScroll))
    .addGroup(gr.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE).addComponent(addButton).addComponent(remButton)));

    gr.setHorizontalGroup(gr.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(gr.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(productName).addComponent(amount).addComponent(description).addComponent(addButton))
            .addGroup(gr.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER).addComponent(productText).addComponent(amountText).addComponent(desScroll).addComponent(remButton))
            .addGroup(gr.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER).addComponent(productList).addComponent(prodScroll)));
```

Comment: Is the GUI resizable? If so, to what elements (or borders) should the extra width or height be added?

Comment: As an aside, I've only known one person who claimed to be able to code a group layout by hand. Most people (who use it) use a drag-and-drop GUI designer. Are you coding it that way?

Comment: To get the layout that looks exactly like your picture the GridBagLayout is probably the easiest. You have 4 columns and 4 rows. A couple of components would need to  span a column or row. Read the tutorial for examples to get your started. (you've been given a link to the tutorial in an answer below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the minority of people would choose to use [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). However, I dislike it (among with `GroupLayout`) since it is "hard to use". I use nested panels instead with various [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). Using only `BorderLayout` and `GridLayout` you can achieve something like the following example, which is totally resizable, giving emphasis to "interaction" components (I mean, there is no reason to resize a constant-texted `JLabel`, right?)

I did not add any comments in purpose, so you can experiment with constants (and layout constraints) and see their reason of existence while having the documentations opened.

Code:

```
public class NestedLayoutManagersExample extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7042997375941726246L;
    private static final int labelsWidth = 80;
    private static final int textFieldColumns = 15;
    private static final int spaceBetweenAllComponents = 10;

    public NestedLayoutManagersExample() {
        super("test");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2, 50, 50));
        contentPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(spaceBetweenAllComponents, spaceBetweenAllComponents,
                spaceBetweenAllComponents, spaceBetweenAllComponents));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        add(createLeftPanel());
        add(createRightPanel());

        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        pack();
    }

    private Component createRightPanel() {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JLabel productListLabel = new JLabel("Product list");
        mainPanel.add(productListLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        JList<String> productList = new JList<>();
        DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
        Arrays.asList("Small Chair", "Big Chair", "Flying Chair").forEach(listModel::addElement);
        productList.setModel(listModel);

        JScrollPane listScrollPane = new JScrollPane(productList);
        mainPanel.add(listScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        return mainPanel;
    }

    private Component createLeftPanel() {

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(spaceBetweenAllComponents, spaceBetweenAllComponents));

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1, spaceBetweenAllComponents, spaceBetweenAllComponents));
        topPanel.add(createStraightPanel("Product Name"));
        topPanel.add(createStraightPanel("Amount"));
        mainPanel.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JLabel label = new JLabel("<html><p style='width:" + labelsWidth + "px';> Description");
        label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
        centerPanel.add(label, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

        centerPanel.add(createTextAreaPanel());

        mainPanel.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        return mainPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createTextAreaPanel() {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(spaceBetweenAllComponents, spaceBetweenAllComponents));

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(1, textFieldColumns);

        JScrollPane textAreaScrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        mainPanel.add(textAreaScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JButton addButton = new JButton("Add");
        buttonsPanel.add(addButton, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

        JButton removeButton = new JButton("Remove");
        buttonsPanel.add(removeButton, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

        mainPanel.add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        return mainPanel;
    }

    private Component createStraightPanel(String labelText) {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JLabel label = new JLabel("<html><p style='width:" + labelsWidth + "px';>" + labelText);
        mainPanel.add(label, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

        JTextField textField = new JTextField(textFieldColumns);

        mainPanel.add(textField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        return mainPanel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new NestedLayoutManagersExample().setVisible(true));
    }
}
```

**Preview:**

[image: preview]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, and sorry for this very late thanks. Your code works perfectly, thanks a lot!

Comment: @AerysS no problem. Take also a look at [what should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)